# Split text between multiple delimiters

Tags: vb.net

I have a rather tricky problem with my ongoing project.
I pretty much need to extract ceritain Strings between muliple delimiters out of a bigger String.
To give you a better understanding, what I mean, here is an example:

```
Some Text that wont be needed 
Some Text that wont be needed 
Some Text that wont be needed 
Some Text that wont be needed 
Some Text that wont be needed 
Textstart (Start-Delimiter) 
Text I want 
Text I want 
Text I want 
Text I want 
Text I want
Textend (End-Delimiter)
```

So far, so easy. But now comes a messy part in. The End-delimiters change sometimes like this

```
Textstart 
Text I want 
Text I want 
Text I want 
Text I want 
Textend2 (another end delimiter)
```

I also solved that Problem, but now since I discovered, that the start delimiter can also occur twice before the next endpart.
Like this:

```
Textstart (Start-Delimiter)
Text I want 
Text I want 
Textstart 
Text I want 
Text I want 
Textend (End-Delimiter)
```

This really is confusing to me. This is the function right now. It works but only if the start delimiter does not occur twice.

I could split the text first by the end strings and after that by the start string, but I don't know hot to split a text by multiple delimiters.

```
Function NewTextGet(ByVal Text As String, ByVal StartString As String, ByVal EndStrings() As String)
    Dim AllBlocks As New List(Of String)
    Dim FirstSplit() As String = Strings.Split(Text, StartString)                    ' Splits Text at Start delimiter
    For Each splt In FirstSplit.Skip(1)
        Dim EndSplit1 = splt.Split({EndStrings(0)}, StringSplitOptions.None)         ' First end delimiter Split
        Dim EndSplit2 = EndSplit1(0).Split({EndStrings(1)}, StringSplitOptions.None) ' Second delimiter Split
        Dim EndSplit3 = EndSplit2(0).Split({EndStrings(2)}, StringSplitOptions.None) ' Third delimiter Split
        If EndSplit3.Length > 1 Then
            AllBlocks.Add(EndSplit3(0))
        ElseIf EndSplit2.Length > 1 Then
            AllBlocks.Add(EndSplit2(0))
        Else
            AllBlocks.Add(EndSplit1(0))
        End If
    Next
    Return AllBlocks
End Function`


I hope I explained this well enough, and thank you for any help :)
```

Comment: Are the delimiters and the data all on their own lines?

Comment: Start-Delimiter got data on the same line 
End delimiter ends the textblock

Answer (score 0):

This version produces a `List(Of List(OF String))`.  So each set of lines will be in a different list:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fileName As String = "C:\Users\mikes\Downloads\gYeziPRE.txt"
    Dim blocks As List(Of List(Of String)) = NewTextGet(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(fileName), "ctxt", New String() {"done", "sdone", "prompt"})
    For i As Integer = 0 To blocks.Count - 1
        Debug.Print("Block: " & i)
        For Each line As String In blocks(i)
            Debug.Print(line)
        Next
        Debug.Print("")
    Next
End Sub

Function NewTextGet(ByVal Text As String, ByVal StartString As String, ByVal EndStrings() As String) As List(Of List(Of String))
    Dim started As Boolean = False
    Dim curBlock As List(Of String)
    Dim AllBlocks As New List(Of List(Of String))
    Dim lines() As String = Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    For Each line As String In lines
        If line.Contains(StartString) Then
            If Not started Then
                started = True
                curBlock = New List(Of String)
            End If
            Dim i As Integer = line.IndexOf(StartString)
            curBlock.Add(line.Substring(i + StartString.Length).Trim())
        ElseIf EndStrings.Contains(line.Trim()) Then
            started = False
            If Not IsNothing(curBlock) Then
                AllBlocks.Add(curBlock)
            End If
            curBlock = Nothing
        ElseIf started = True AndAlso Not IsNothing(curblock) Then
            curBlock.Add(line.Trim())
        End If
    Next
    If Not IsNothing(curBlock) Then
        AllBlocks.Add(curBlock)
    End If
    Return AllBlocks
End Function
```

Output:

```
Block: 0
"What's up?"
para "All these Trainers"
line "look the same, but"
para "only one is the"
line "leader!"

Block: 1
"Am I Koji?"
para "Why, yes, I am!"

Block: 2
"Well done!"
para "Here!"
para "The Fist Badge!"

Block: 3
"<PLAYER> received"
line "Fist Badge."

Block: 4
"Here!"
para "Take this TM!"

Block: 5
"Hah!"
para "That was joyful"
line "sparring!"

Block: 6
"Japanese"
line "onomatopoeia"
cont "are so kawaii!"

Block: 7
"Hiri hiri!"

Block: 8
"Uwaaaa!"

Block: 9
"Well, you chose"
line "unwisely."

Block: 10
"You have more"
line "chances."

Block: 11
"Koji is hot."
para "Dressing like him"
line "is<...>"
para "wonderful!"

Block: 12
"Wasn't supposed"
line "to happen!"

Block: 13
"Can't wait for"
line "Halloween!"

Block: 14
"Ninjas are so"
line "cool!"

Block: 15
"Not skilled"
line "enough!"

Block: 16
"Time to study"
line "ninjutsu instead"
cont "of pretending."
```

Comment: This looks really good, but as I tried it it only returned the first line after the start string only. I will try around with it. :)

Comment: Can you update your post with some actual data?...and start/end strings?

Comment: Yes I can do that, but the texts I am working with are not for public presentation. I will change the Text and post it here in a few minutes.

I post it in my main Question, it's too long

Comment: Of course, sanitize it.  Just wanted to test with something.  =)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3WLDdxaB
Edits need to be approved :P 
I hope its enough for you like this.

Comment: ah...you have data on the same line as the start delimiter.

Comment: Is there ever any data on the same line as a end delimiter?

Comment: Yeah stupid me ^^.. I wrote my example the wrong way :/

Comment: No theres never data on the end delimiter. The block ends with it

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zTRXpuFS
This is how I changed your code but it sometimes does not split one of the end delimiters

Comment: It works now :)) I did it this way. https://pastebin.com/sESyfCgM
But theres still the problem of the start delimiter  if it comes up twice it behaves stangely

Comment: Try my last edit...seems to work with your test data.

Comment: Got it.  Will test again.

Comment: So I'll need the start delimiter and a list of the end delimiters.

Comment: start would be always = "ctxt """
ends are = {"done", "sdone", "prompt"}

Comment: I tried your code. It works very well, but it skips the parts with the double startstring. 
I can post the part that is not working properly. This is the exact thing i couldnt get to work.

Comment: Nevermind! This is perfect thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: The only problem now is that it does not return the exact original string.
It seems to remove empty lines. But I also need them. EG: https://pastebin.com/bgZAjQNH
Line 2 needs to be returned too, because i need to replace the original part later with something else.

Comment: Edited the code.  Simply changed the Split() line to `Dim lines() As String = Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)` so it will keep the blank lines.

Comment: Dude thank you so much. I finally can finish up all that stuff :))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Function NewTextGet(ByVal RawText As String, ByVal StartString As String, ByVal EndStrings() As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim bEnd As List(Of String) = EndStrings.ToList
        bEnd.Insert(0, StartString)

        Dim Blocks As New List(Of String)
        Dim Splits() As String = Split(RawText, vbNewLine, , CompareMethod.Text)

        For x As Integer = 0 To Splits.Length - 1
1:
            Dim block As String = ""
            If Splits(x).Contains(StartString) Then
                block = Splits(x)
                For y As Integer = x + 1 To Splits.Length - 1
                    Dim BlockEnd As Boolean = False
                    For Each s As String In bEnd
                        If Splits(y).Contains(s) Then BlockEnd = True
                    Next
                    block &= vbNewLine
                    If BlockEnd Then
                        If Splits(y).Contains(StartString) Then
                            Blocks.Add(block & vbNewLine)
                            x = y - 1
                            GoTo 1
                        End If
                        x = y + 1
                        block &= Splits(y)
                        Blocks.Add(block & vbNewLine)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    block &= Splits(y)
                Next
            End If
        Next

        Return Blocks
    End Function
```

usage

```
For Each s As String In NewTextGet(Raw, "ctxt", New String() {"sdone", "done", "prompt"})
    TextBox2.Text &= s & "=======" & vbNewLine
Next
```

use this order {**"sdone", "done"**, "prompt"} to avoid conflection while spliting

Comment: Hi I tried this and I get the same problem again. It won't sage both startstrings if it comes up twice.
Sometimes there is two startstrings in one textblock before the enddelimiter

Comment: You mean that blocks are something like [For Next] loop inside another [For Next] loop ,Right!?

Comment: Yes sort of, have you seen the original syntax?

Comment: Your above example has 2 **Textstart** and just one **Textend** !! ,if the start count equal ends count i think i can give you an answer, if not i think you have to expand your example with more blocks + manually extracted blocks,to clarify the relation between start and its end

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6qhna9ua Here. This file contains almost any scenario.

Comment: @Flack420 I edit my answer  , line 149 will not included bc no start delimiter